# Why my promise not replacing data in constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Please let me know where I am doing mistake.
I have class with constructor and 2 methods. I want that method find() will push data from query to array. I don't understand where I am loosing array values and it's empty for other method or just checking value.

```
class DeleteOffers {

    constructor()
    {
        this.index = 'index';
        this.array = [];
        this.body = {
            query: {
                range: {
                    date_end: {
                        gt: format.asString('yyyy-mm-dd', new Date()),
                        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
                    }
                },
            },
            _source: "_id"
        };
    }

    find() {
        return client.search({index: this.index, body: this.body})
            .then(response => {
                var that = this;
                return response.hits.hits.map(value => that.array.push(value._id))
            })
            .catch(error =>
                console.log(error.message)
            )

    }

    remove() {
        console.log(this.array); // WHY IT'S EMPTY?
    }

}

const object = new DeleteOffers();
object.find(); // []
object.remove(); // []
return res.json(object.array); // []
```

Comment: is `response.hits.hits` correct or should it be `response.hits`? Have you tested/debugged the function to ensure that you're getting a valid response back and `console.log`ged the `response` data structure?

Comment: It's 100% valid syntax. I can do console.log(response.hits.hits._id) inside of arrow function and it gives me what I want. But can't flush/save it to class array.

Comment: I revoked your changes, please don't edit in recommendations. Your code was fine `var that = this` is unneccessary (you can also just access `this` in the map part) but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to *await* the find operation:

```
 (async function() {
    const object = new DeleteExpiredRentalOffers();
    await object.find();
    object.remove();
})();
```

or:

```
 const object = new DeleteExpiredRentalOffers();
 object.find().then(() =>  object.remove());
```

Answer (score 1):

You call remove after find, but console.log in find need wait promise ended, but in remove don't need. Now, you can access to this pointer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited code.
Yeah, but now I can't access properties in my constructor. this.array is null.
I don't understand too, why it's calling function remove() before find(). It seems not logically for me.

Comment: You are welcome, check it can fix your error or not.

Comment: Refresh page. ;)

Comment: You create `that`  with `this` (pointer inside promise, should copy this in `find`, not inside `then`)

Comment: You call `remove` after `find`, but `console.log` in `find` need wait promise ended, but in `remove` don't need.
Now, you can access to this pointer.

Comment: `You use arrow function, so pointer this is not your object` wrong.

Comment: Thanks for help. Understood now. @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ

Comment: @JonasW. thank your response, some example I tested has wrong with this of arrow function, I going to research abount that.